# Why can't i use NVelocity with the Asp.net MVC Beta?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nvelocity

I have added the required assemblies and registered the NVelocityViewFactory in global.asax.cs page but when i run the site i get the following error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.Web.Mvc` was moved to ASP.NET Futures. It's on CodePlex.